# finding package aka default-scoped members of java classes

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to find all the default-scoped, aka package-scoped, class members in my project. (Other scopes are no problem, since I can search for the keyword public/protected/private, but there's no keyword to search for in this case.)

Is there an eclipse plugin or anything that can do this kind of search?

```
public class Foo {
    private int a;   // these are easy
    protected int b; // to find,
    public int c;    // thanks to keywords

    int d; // but ones like this?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at javap:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html

It's primarily intended for disassembling classes, but it also lets you include/exclude class members of different scope (private vs public, for example)

Comment: Looks like it might get you something slightly easier to grep, but still a lot of extraneous stuff and still no keywords or anything to distinguish the package-scope members...

Comment: I was going to suggest javadoc, but it appears it will give you similar results and similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since javap does not appear to be a suitable solution and I don't know of any suitable plugin, you may have to write your own.

```
Feed it a list of classes.
for each class
    Use Class.forName(className) to get the class object
    use getDeclared{Classes,Fields,Methods,Constructors} to get the members.
    for each member
        Use java.lang.reflect.Modifiers.is{Public,Private,Protected}(member.getModifiers())
        It is default if all three are false
        If default report that member
        You decide whether and how to recurse into inner classes.
```

I guess that solution will not work for classes nested inside methods.  (Neither would javap, javadoc solve classes nested inside methods.)  It will make things much simpler if you can just assert that you code does not have classes nested inside methods.

Comment: Thanks emory, writing code to do it using reflection is a good idea. Somebody should add this to eclipse. :)